# Python - how to create a bit struct?

Tags: python

I'm trying to serialize a bit value (0 or 1) in Python. Looking at the `struct` library, it seems the way to do this would be the following:

```
>>> import struct
>>> s = struct.Struct('b')
>>> s.pack(123)
  b'{'
```

I'm a little struck (ha) by why I'm able to pack the value 123. Shouldn't I only be allowed 0 or 1?

Digging a little deeper shows that a range of numbers is possible:

```
b.pack(567)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2963, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-13-a612cd3ee2b8>", line 1, in <module>
    b.pack(567)
struct.error: byte format requires -128 <= number <= 127
```

Calling `s.size` shows that the size is 1 - why am I allowed to pack more than 0 or 1?

Comment: I think 'b' stands for byte, not bit. So you can pack any number that can be represented using one byte. CAn you explain in more details what are you trying to do? What is your input and output?

Comment: @Shir Indeed, and that is exactly what the error suggests (`byte format requires -128 <= number <= 127`)

Comment: @DeepSpace Ah that would make sense - `b` stands for byte, not bit here. Is there a way to store one bit?

Comment: I'm not aware of any language (or underlying hardware) that allows the storage of a single bit; the byte is almost universally the smallest chunk of addressable storage/data. Just use a byte, and ignore the wasted higher-order bits.

Comment: Sounds good - thanks for the quick answer

Comment: The return value of `struct.pack` is a `str` (Python 2) or `bytes` (Python 3) object, so you'll always get back at least a single byte.

Comment: To avoid illegal input (for example 2, if you want only 0 or 1)- you can use bool, which is `struct.Struct(?)`